# O que é a abreviação "node:"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Reparei em alguns projetos que alguns módulos são importados usando um `node:` antes do nome do módulo.

Ex:

```
import { readFile } from 'node:fs/promises'
```

O que normalmente (pelo que vi em toda minha carreira) é feito somente o `'fs/promises'`, sem esse `node:`.

O que é isto? Existe um motivo para seu uso?

Comment: Muito bom, a proposta de trazer um conteúdo de forma objetiva é ótima para o site/comunidade. Realmente a dúvida poderia (talvez) se tornar em múltiplas duvidas no futuro, isso agrega bom conteúdo ao site, +1 para pergunta e resp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Protocolo Node.js

Isto se chama [protocolo de importação Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#node-imports) (*Node.js `node:` protocol imports*) e são usados ao se **importar módulos nativos da plataforma**.

Antigamente:

```
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';
```

Com o protocolo:

```
import * as fs from 'node:fs/promises';
```

Este recurso foi adicionando nas versões `v14.13.1` e `v12.20.0` do Node para ser usado nas importações via  [ESM import](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#modules-ecmascript-modules) **somente**. Posteriormente, foi adicionado nas versões `v16.0.0` e `v14.18.0` com suporte adicional ao [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules-commonjs-modules) `require()`.

#### Finalidade

Como descrito na [documentação](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#node-imports):

> Os **URLs** são suportados como um meio alternativo para carregar os módulos integrados do Node.js. Esse esquema de URL permite que módulos internos sejam referenciados por *strings* de **URL absolutas válidas**.

Em outras palavras, o que isto nos diz?:

- Uma forma de deixar explicito no código, quais módulos nativos do Node.js são importados.
- Impede riscos de um módulo de terceiro se sobrepor a algum módulo nativo do Node.js, o que se torna de extrema importância a medida que a plataforma adiciona/cria novas *libs* nativas, como por exemplo a API (não nativa anteriormente) [fetch](https://fusebit.io/blog/node-fetch/?utm_source=www.google.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=none), com suporte experimental na versão `v17.5` via flag `--experimental-fetch`.
- E claro (talvez o principal), não gerar conflitos com futuras especificações do JavaScript ([standard library proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-built-in-modules))